# Is it possible to write (a*b)+(c*d) in a way that doesn't use order of operations?

Tags: math, programming-languages

Alright, so [warsow](http://www.warsow.net/) has some pretty excellent hud code with the exception that the math logic is a bit screwy.

**Input:**

```
a*b + c*d
```

**Interpreted as:**

```
((d*c) + b) * a
```

As you can see, the game does a series of operations in reverse order without regard to order of operations. Parentheses do not work in the hud code. It must be a linear series of operations to come up with the end result. Is this possible?
I understand that it would be better to implement proper math into the hud code, but this is way more fun imo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a*b + a/c*d -> ((d*c/a) + b) * a
```

granted normal algebra holds

Comment: how do you get from `a*b + c*d` to `a*b + a/c*d`?

Comment: @Aaron its how its interpreted

Comment: I didn't get a chance to test it, since the idea has been dropped. Your answer is much appreciated nevertheless.